# creating arrays of Jbuttons in windowbuilder

Tags: java, arrays, swing

is there anyway to make arrays of J Buttons in eclipse. i want to use the window builder is there anyway to do this??
my program kinda needs to use an array cause i have to use loops and i cant do it if my buttons are of different variable names.
i found some tutorials but there are manually done. i want to use windowbuilder to create the same output of jbuttons

can someone provide tutorials or videos on how i can achieve this? thank you

have this code so far.

```
public class Sungka_GUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Sungka_GUI frame = new Sungka_GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Sungka_GUI() {
        setResizable(false);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Sungka_GUI.class.getResource("/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/icons/JavaCup32.png")));
        setTitle("Sungka");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 675, 370);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);                                   
        JLabel frame = new JLabel("");
        frame.setBounds(0, -13, 669, 354);
        Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/wood3.png")).getImage();                                    
        frame.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));                                
        getContentPane().add(frame);
    }
}
```

Comment: that codes for the buttons that i tried didnt work

Comment: Probably not, that's not really how WindowBuilder works.  As a hint, I'd avoid Window Builder any way and the effort to learn to code your UI's by hand, it will teach you more neat tricks and ideas then Window Builder can and will also free up a lot of your code

Comment: i want to use code for the buttons, i think i will just use the window builder for the design of the program? is that ok? i just need to make the buttons work

Answer (score 0):

Extend A JPanel class, create some for loop that creates and initializes (adds them to this Jpanel, initializes event listeners etc...) the collection of buttons you created, add some getter for this collection. In window builder add some JPanel and later in your code change the JPanel class of this element to be your class that  is extending JPanel.